# ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"

Tags: sql, database, shell, psql

I've got a PSQL guidebook which says that first thing you should do before start usin' psql shell is to set an encoding and it offers to type `chcp 1251` to allow us to type "*;*". So it doesn't work, but `SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8'` works. Could someone explain me why, please?

Answer (score 0):

I had such an error due to the presence of the Cyrillic character "M" in the request text.

[image]